# Overlap TableViewCell or Negative distance between cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a TableView with overlapped cells based on the below mockup. [Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY6S8.png)

(You can see that the posterImage is larger than the cells.
Is there anyway to set this or set the distance between cells = -5, for example?

Comment: I think a UICollectionView might be more suitable. You could set it to vertical scroll with different sizes for odd and even items alternate lines.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that will be to turn off clipping to bounds on your contentView of UITableViewCell:

```
func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

This will allow to place images outside the cell boundaries.

Remember that with any approach where UITableViewCell's overlap each other, you may find problems with "z" ordering - which is mixing a lot while scrolling.

But from your mockup it seems that it's easy to solve, by just making UITableViewCell's transparent